# Multiply tuple values in dictionary and take final sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary like this containing tuples:

```
d = {'itemA': (1, 0.5), 'itemB': (2, 0.3), 'itemC': (3, 0.7)}
```

How can I multiply each tuple individually and then take the overall sum?

```
result = (1 * 0.5) + (2 * 0.3) + (3 * 0.7) = 3.2
```

Comment: By looping over the values in the dictionary, multiplying the elements of each tuple, and summing the result. How would you do it on paper? Write down the steps you would take, and now you have an algorithm. Translate that algorithm to python and voila, you have your answer

Comment: Just one of many ways: `sum(map(math.prod, d.values()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul 

d = {'itemA': (1, 0.5), 'itemB': (2, 0.3), 'itemC': (3, 0.7)}

d1={k:reduce(mul, t) for k,t in d.items()}

>>> sum(d1.values())
3.1999999999999997
```

Or simply:

```
>>> sum(reduce(mul, t) for t in d.values())
3.1999999999999997
```

Or, an even better way pointed out in comments:

```
import math
>>> sum(map(math.prod, d.values()))
3.1999999999999997
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain Python:

```py
d = {'itemA': (1, 0.5), 'itemB': (2, 0.3), 'itemC': (3, 0.7)}
sum_tot = 0
for tpl in d.values():
    prod_tpl = 1
    for item in tpl:
        prod_tpl *= item
    sum_tot += prod_tpl
print(sum_tot)
```

Output:

```
3.1999999999999997
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'itemA': (1, 0.5), 'itemB': (2, 0.3), 'itemC': (3, 0.7)}
result = 0

for item in d:
    result += d[item][0] * d[item][1]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'itemA': (1, 0.5), 'itemB': (2, 0.3), 'itemC': (3, 0.7)}
total = 0
for tup in d.values():
    total += tup[0]*tup[1]
print(total)
```